# When to use Eloquent (ORM) over Fluent (Query Builder)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Maybe due to my Codeigniter background, I just don't find myself enjoying Laravel 4's Eloquent ORM a lot. Say I would like to write a query that order a list of posts by id, descending, how can Eloquent beat the clarity of `DB::table('posts')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();`?

Is there a good reason to use Eloquent over Fluent, was it mostly for joining tables?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I came from codeigniter also and this is my experience:
I use Eloquent and Fluent usually together. Eloquent is a thing that allows you to work nicely with relations, CRUD operations etc. When you need to do some SQL operations you can easily add some fluent functions

In the example you mentioned above I see you have posts table. If you have a post model then the same thing written using Eloquent is:

```
Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

So as I get it if you extends Eloquent than

```
Model_name::some_functions
```

is the same as

```
DB::table('table_name')->some_functions
```

The real power comes when you need to create or update a model, or, for example, get post comments. Than it becomes easily:

```
$comments = Post::find($id)->comments;
```

So the answer is - you have to use fluent functions to get ordered list. You can use them both with DB::table('posts')->orderBy or Post::orderBy

Comment: thx, just to confirm, for `Post::find($id)->comments;` the `comments` method, does it have to run against `Post` table, or can it be a join between `Post` and `Comment` table?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You have post and comments table, you have post_id in comments table and you describe a method in post class (function comments() { return $this->hasMany('comment'); }. And also you have Comment class too. Then you can use Post::find($id)->comments which will join your post with comments (like selet * from posts join comments on comments.post_id = posts.id)

Comment: As a clarification Eloquent inherits from Fluent so basically everything you have in Fluent, can be used in Eloquent.

If you're doing `Post::find($id)->comments`, you're not doing join by default but first `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$id` and after that `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id=$id` but only when you invoke/ask for `->comments`. 

If you want to load all the relations at the same time, check out [Eloquent's Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading).

Comment: Sorry I might be asking a dumb question.  If we know the post_id already, why does Eloquent have to generate 2 requests to get comments?  From my understanding, wouldn't one query (directly from the comments table) passing in the post_id be sufficient?  Sounds really inefficient the way it is it seems.  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: @Tomas Cheng You can always tell Laravel to make the query more efficient by specifying joins manually when reading models, in combination with `with` - Laravel is smart enough to detect that related objects are loaded through the specified join and then it does not create additional SQL queries.

Comment: Important thing to note is that Eloquent (model) and Query builders (DB) are two different ORM approaches. The first one is ActiveRecord, and the second one is closed to DataMapper. Laravel has made this border a bit fuzzy because in Laravel with Eloquent model you can perform actions which normally come from DataMapper world and not from ActiveRecord world (like specifying JOINs manually).

Answer (score 3):

Using models and Eloquent, you can also write custom functions in your model class for performing common operations like, say, outputting a couple concatenated fields.

for instance:

```
<?php
class User extends Eloquent {
    //Standard Relation Function
    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
    //Custom function
    public function fullname() {
        return $this->firstName.' '.$this->lastName;
    }
}

//Somewhere else in your code, if you need a users full name...
$user = User::find(3);
$name = $user->fullname();
```

Comment: We can take this even further with the getXAttribute() functions too. Eg: getFullNameAttribute() then we can just do $user->fullName.

Comment: @euantorano Indeed, good point!